# Why are my Google Fonts only appearing for my IP?

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts

I'm working on a site that uses the Roboto Condensed and Montserrat Google fonts. I have included it as such:

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,300i,400,500,500i,600|Roboto|Roboto+Condensed:400,700" as="stylesheet">
```

And am using it in my CSS like:

```
.page-heading {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    color: #333333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    clear: both;
}
```

This seemed to work for me, both on my local machine and on the remote site, so I released my work.

Later that day the client called saying all the fonts were broken, sending me screenshots of the font defaulting to a serif Times New Roman font. I asked that he clear his cache, which he did, and test on multiple browsers and but he still got the same result.

Of course I cleared my own cache here, tested on Incognito Mode, multiple browsers, and via a VPN. I even had my co-workers check. No issues here, the fonts appear as they should.

So I called a few friends outside of work and got them to check the site. They all reported the same issue as the client - fonts are defaulting to Times New Roman, no sign of Roboto.

I really don't know what to do as I can't even re-create the error here.

Would anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Would you be able to post the link for us to test? As far as I know, there's no such thing as IP restriction in GoogleFonts. There's also nothing showing that in the code you posted. Are you sure the people outside your work (not your client) couldn't see it either? You can also check the OS (Mac VS Windows), to try to find a pattern.
Another thing you can do (and ask your client to do), is use the browser inspector and look at "computed styles", to make sure the google font is there.

Comment: maybe it is an security issue which (security on server) prevent the stylesheet from load. open F12 and check if the stylesheet load from network